# Swift optionals for Dictionarys

Tags: swift

```
MFSAPIManager().registerNewUser(userFirstName!, lastName: userLastName!, userTypeId: 1, email: userEmail!, password: userPassword!, completionHandler: { (response) in

        guard response.error == nil else {
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
                self.displayAlertViewController(title: "Error", message: "Der Benutzer konnte nicht registriert werden")
            }
            return
        }

        if let serverResponse = response.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            let newUserReference = serverResponse["data"]!["userReference"]

            if (newUserReference != nil) {
                self.currentPLISTData["userReference"] = newUserReference
                dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
                    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registrierung erfolgreich", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) in
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    })
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }


    })
```

I get an error message that I need to change:

```
let newUserReference = serverResponse["data"]["userReference"]
```

to

```
let newUserReference = serverResponse["data"]!["userReference"]
```

so unwrapping the `["data"]` component. I am confused why this is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A Swift dictionary *always* returns an Optional.**

It means that to be able to subscript `serverResponse["data"]` with `["userReference"]` you first have to unwrap `serverResponse["data"]`.

It can be done unsafely, like in your example, or safely with something like `if let`:

```
if let data = serverResponse["data"] {
    let newUserReference = data["userReference"]
}
```

Also note that the compiler might not now the type of `serverResponse["data"]` so you may have to downcast it for being able to subscript to it, for example:

```
if let data = serverResponse["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    let newUserReference = data["userReference"]
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a `Dictionary<Key,Value>` by subscript returns a `Value?`. This is because the key-value pair you are looking for might not be in the dictionary. Thus it returns an optional, set if it finds the key, unset if it doesn't.

I would handle it this way, using optional chaining:

```
if let serverResponse = response.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>,
       newUserReference = serverResponse["data"]?["userReference"] {
  ...
}
```

By combining all the `if..let` statements into one you reduce the ['pyramid of doom'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_%28programming%29).

Eric D makes a good point that you should test the type of the first subscript, I would do it like this:

```
if let serverResponse = response.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>,
       data = serverResponse["data"] as? [String:AnyObject],
       newUserReference = data["userReference"] {
  ...
}
```